# XamlSpy prevent me from doing actions

Tags: xaml, uwp

I installed XamlSpy using NuGet in my UWP app.
I debug my application and connect it successfully using the XamlSpy.

The problem is that every mouse hover is responses by XamlSpy what prevents me from clicking on buttons etc'...

How can I start inspect only when needed ? 
I tried CTRL+Shift without success...

Answer (score 0):

> How can I start inspect only when needed

According to [this article](http://xamlspy.com/learn/quick-start/inapp), `Ctrl+Shift` is worked for XAML Spy 2. By testing on my side, I guess you are using XAML Spy 3.

In that case, when you are using the  [XAML Spy desktop app](http://xamlspy.com/learn/desktop-app-user-guide) to inspect, the "Select Visual" button which is for moving your mouse to the app, and click to select a visual in the user interface, is highlighted by default. You may need to click it to not highlight the button to stop inspecting, and click again can  start inspecting again when you needed.

[image]

Comment: Yes that is the obvious behavior but it's not working for me... all the time the red dashed lines focus on mouse over...
even with the xamlspy desktop app closed...